# Set trigger order usage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

we can set order option of trigger to first, last or none by use `sp_settriggerorder` command. I want to know what's significance of set trigger order. and when necessity using this option?

I use `SQL Server 2008 R2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One purpose would be if you want one trigger to perform some form of sanity checks before other triggers (which may have expensive actions) fire. If the `first` trigger causes a `ROLLBACK` to occur, the other triggers aren't fired:

```
create table T (
    ID int not null
)
go
create trigger T1
on T
after insert
as
    RAISERROR('T1',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
go
create trigger T2
on T
after insert
as
    RAISERROR('T2',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
go
create trigger T3
on T
after insert
as
    RAISERROR('T3',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
go
sp_settriggerorder 'T1','First','Insert'
go
sp_settriggerorder 'T3','Last','Insert'
go
insert into T(ID) values (1)
--T1
--T2
--T3

--(1 row(s) affected)
go
alter trigger T1
on T
after insert
as
    RAISERROR('T1',10,1) WITH NOWAIT
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
go
insert into T(ID) values (2)
--T1
--Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
--The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

Answer (score 0):

[It specifies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186762.aspx) in what order AFTER triggers fire when multiple triggers apply to a SQL statement. You can specify only one first or last trigger for a specific table, database or server.

Comment: It Seem that don't difference in execute triggers by order. can you say a example for describe  cost of set triggers order.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The cost of applying a trigger order is negligible.